# Problem finding data in couchbase replicas 4.5.1

Tags: couchbase

I have a problem with my cluster couchbase, I have 4 (four) servers in my cluster, I have 3 (three) replicated number, that is the original data and + 3 copies, my created documents are 100% available for consultation while the cluster contains the 4 nodes, what caught my attention and generated very strange is the fact that if one of the machines is unavailable the data of the document are not available or are located when I perform a search.

To improve understanding, I have this cluster with 4 servers to ensure resilience and high availability of data, but it is to lose one of the machines and the data is no longer found when I execute query in one of the 3 replicas.

My 4 nodes of this server are with data, index and query services enabled.

Has anyone gone through this before?

[this my cluster services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usHwE.png)

[in this image, my big question is if this option would help "View index replicas"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuy47.png)

Comment: Are you using N1QL queries? Be aware that by default each index is placed on only one node, so if it goes down, the index is unavailable. If you want higher reliability for indexes, you need to replicate them across multiple nodes.

Comment: Hi, ...Yes, I understand that each index by default is placed on only one node, but in the scenario I have added the data, index and querys services for all nodes, ... only the services it is not enough to replicated the indexes? (thoughtful).
In the couchbase exists in the bucket already created the option of "View index replicas", but this option will only work and will be available only when creating new buckets, it does not work for bucket already created.

Comment: Do you have auto-failover turned on, or are you failing over the node manually?

Comment: Sorry, but I not use the N1QL query way, I use the api based in one lib nodejs and the query search by url and key of document.

Comment: Yes i have auto-failover turned on

Comment: And did autofailover perform a failover when you failed one of the nodes?  If not, you'll want to use the replica read API.  If failover occurred, you should be able to access the doc in the alternate location.  Note that by default, Couchbase only gets data from the primary location to ensure consistency.  Failover promotes a replica to a new primary.